# Migrate to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, migration, azure-devops, devops

My Dev team has created an Azure DevOPS on their own personal account and want to move it to our centralized Azure Tenant.  I have access to the the Azure Tenant where I wish to host the devops.  note I have visualstudio.com and dev.azure.com and not sure which one to use.  currently there are no DEVOPS showing in our Azure Portal and this is where I would like to move everything to to have centralized controls.  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps and Azure are two separate products, you don't manage Azure Devops through the Azure portal. You can link your Azure DevOps organisation to your Azure AD for authentication however.

To create an Azure DevOps organisation you can follow [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/sign-up-invite-teammates?view=azure-devops).

Once you have an organisation, unfortunately moving a project from one organisation to another is not an easy thing. There is not a simple migration tool, you would need to look at importing any Git Repos and then migrating any working items using something like [this](https://medium.com/medialesson/move-azure-devops-work-items-from-one-organization-to-another-42ad8370e46b).

Comment: Just to add, it is always possible to change Azure DevOps organization's AAD tenant and remap users for the new federation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops